# How do you fix type mismatch Run-time error '13'

Tags: excel, vba

I keep running my code, but it keeps spitting back that I have to debug the run-time error. I'm not sure what is wrong with the code or how to fix it.

```
Sub Circles()
Dim X1 As Double
Dim Y1 As Double
Dim X2 As Double
Dim Y2 As Double
Dim X3 As Double
Dim Y3 As Double

X1 = Range("C3").Value
Y1 = Range("D3").Value
X2 = Range("C4").Value
Y2 = Range("D4").Value
X3 = Range("C5").Value
Y3 = Range("D5").Value

Dim point1() As Double
Dim point2() As Double
Dim point3() As Double

point1 = Array(X1, Y1)
point2 = Array(X2, Y2)
point3 = Array(X3, Y3)

Slo1 = Slope(point1, point2)
Slo2 = Slope(point2, point3)

Dim Mid1() As Double
Mid1 = Midpoint(point1, point2)
Dim Mid2() As Double
Mid2 = Midpoint(point2, point3)

Dim line1() As Double
line1 = Array(Mid1(0), Mid1(1), Slo1)
Dim line2() As Double
line2 = Array(Mid2(0), Mid2(1), Slo2)

Dim Final() As Double
Final = Center(line1, line2)
Dim FinalX As Double
Dim FinalY As Double
FinalX = Final(0)
FinalY = Final(1)

Range("G3").Value = Application.Transpose(FinalX)
Range("G4").Value = Application.Transpose(FinalY)
End Sub
```

The line with "point1 = Array(X1, Y1)" is the line that has the error. I was expecting it to just run and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: The `Array` function returns a Variant containing an array. You have `Point1` declared as a Double. Hence **type mismatch**. One fix would be to declare `Point1` as Variant. Another would be to assign the variables one at a time, instead of using the `Array` function.

Comment: After I changed that, it said that I have a "Compile error: Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected" In the line that says "Final = Center (line1, line2)" Any suggestions as to how I would go about fixing that?

Comment: You'll need to figure out if your variable types are not what is expected, and also any possible errors in your `Center` user defined function.

Answer (score -1):

> The line with "point1 = Array(X1, Y1)" is the line that has the error. I was expecting it to just run and I'm not sure how to fix it.

this is the problem:

```
Dim point1() As Double
Dim point2() As Double
Dim point3() As Double
```

The problem is that you declare the `point` variables with no size. `point1(?)`
the easy way to fix it is to commet the declarations

```
'Dim point1() As Double
'Dim point2() As Double
'Dim point3() As Double
```

or you can play with the idea of `reDIM`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement